# How can I refactor these two functions with repeating code?

Tags: c#, refactoring, code-cleanup

I'm trying to refactor my code for higher readability and I'm new to this.

I have two functions called **UpFirst()** and **RightFirst()** and they include common lines of code and I want to clean the repeating code.
Could you show me a good way to clean them from repeating lines?

```cs
private bool UpFirst()
{
    var sameBlocks = new List<Tiles>();
    var isAnyMatch = false;

    for (var x = 0; x < _RowCount; x++)
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < _ColumnCount; y++)
        {
            if (y > _ColumnCount - _MinNumberToBlast)
                continue;

            var currentBlock = _tiles[x, y];

            var isAllMatch = true;
            for (var i = 1; i < _MinNumberToBlast; i++)
            {
                var blockToCheck = _tiles[x, y + i];

                var isMatch = currentBlock.Color == blockToCheck.Color;
                isAllMatch = isMatch;
                if (!isMatch) break;
            }

            if (isAllMatch)
            {
                isAnyMatch = true;
                sameBlocks.Add(currentBlock);

                var newBlocks = FloodFill(x, y);

                foreach (var block in newBlocks.Where(block => !sameBlocks.Contains(block)))
                {
                    sameBlocks.Add(block);
                }

                var number = sameBlocks.Count;
                var matchType = TileGroupType.Default;

                if (number > _ConditionACount)
                {
                    matchType = TileGroupType.A;

                    if (number > _ConditionBCount)
                    {
                        matchType = TileGroupType.B;

                        if (number > _ConditionCCount)
                        {
                            matchType = TileGroupType.C;
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (var block in sameBlocks)
                {
                    block.SetMatchGroupType(matchType);
                }
            }

            sameBlocks.Clear();
        }
    }

    return isAnyMatch;
}
```

```cs
private bool RightFirst()
{
    var sameBlocks = new List<Tiles>();
    var isAnyMatch = false;

    for (var y = 0; y < _ColumnCount; y++)
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < _RowCount; x++)
        {
            if (x > _RowCount - _MinNumberToBlast)
                continue;

            var currentBlock = _tiles[x, y];
            currentBlock.SetMatchGroupType(TileGroupType.Default);

            var isAllMatch = true;
            for (var i = 1; i < _MinNumberToBlast; i++)
            {
                var blockToCheck = _tiles[x + i, y];

                var isMatch = currentBlock.Color == blockToCheck.Color;
                isAllMatch = isMatch;
                if (!isMatch) break;
            }

            if (isAllMatch)
            {
                isAnyMatch = true;
                sameBlocks.Add(currentBlock);

                var newBlocks = FloodFill(x, y);

                foreach (var block in newBlocks.Where(block => !sameBlocks.Contains(block)))
                {
                    sameBlocks.Add(block);
                }

                var number = sameBlocks.Count;
                var matchType = TileGroupType.Default;

                if (number > _ConditionACount)
                {
                    matchType = TileGroupType.A;

                    if (number > _ConditionBCount)
                    {
                        matchType = TileGroupType.B;

                        if (number > _ConditionCCount)
                        {
                            matchType = TileGroupType.C;
                        }
                    }
                }

                foreach (var block in sameBlocks)
                {
                    block.SetMatchGroupType(matchType);
                }
            }

            sameBlocks.Clear();
        }
    }

    return isAnyMatch;
}
```

thank you!

I tried creating a third function including the **if(isAllMatch)** block and call it from both of them but didn't work because I had to define x and y and I could not handle it.

Comment: self documenting code is great. done right you can get away without any comments in the code because the method name is descriptive enough to explain the complexity within. I look and see code that makes a lot of sense to a computer but is hard to read. as the human it's hard to decipher what it does or what is common. in general I think you know what you need to do. it just comes down to making each block smaller and passing in what it needs. refactoring after the fact is hard especially if dependencies are out of control but you get better and get into a mindset when writing future code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a "neutral" method having parameters for the first and second count and a delegate to get the coordinates in the right order

```cs
private bool ProcessTiles(int count1, int count2,
                          Func<int, int, (int, int)> getXY)
{
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < count1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < count2; j++)
        {
            if (j > count2 - _MinNumberToBlast)
                continue;

            var (x, y) = getXY(i, j);

            Tiles currentBlock = _tiles[x, y];

            bool isAllMatch = true;
            for (int k = 1; k < _MinNumberToBlast; k++)
            {
                var (dx, dy) = getXY(0, k);
                var blockToCheck = _tiles[x + dx, y + dy];
                ...
            }
            ...
            var newBlocks = FloodFill(x, y);
            ...
        }
    }
}

private bool UpFirst()
{
    ProcessTiles(_RowCount, _ColumnCount, (i, j) => (i, j));
}

private bool RightFirst()
{
    ProcessTiles(_ColumnCount, _RowCount, (i, j) => (j, i));
}
```

`Func<int, int, (int, int)> getXY` is a function that takes a pair of indexes and returns a tuple with those indexes. `UpFirst` passes the lambda expression `(i, j) => (i, j)` to return the indexes in the same order, whereas `RightFirst` uses `(i, j) => (j, i)` to invert the indexes.

`var (x, y) = getXY(i, j);` then gets the the right x, y values from the neutral indexes. Later we get the index added to either x or y with

```cs
var (dx, dy) = getXY(0, k);
var blockToCheck = _tiles[x + dx, y + dy];
```

In `UpFirst` we will get `dx = 0, dy = k` and in `RightFirst` we will get `dx = k, dy = 0`.